# Knockout.js: Is it possible to make ONE-WAY data-binding with 'with'?

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, two-way-binding

In Knockout documentation, it's said that one-way data-binding is possible if we do NOT use ko.observable(...): http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

However, this following code doesn't work as I expect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form data-bind="with: selectedMerchant">
        <input data-bind="value: name"></input>
        <button data-bind="click: change"> CHANGE </button>
        <button data-bind="click: show"> SHOW </button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function PartnersViewModel() {
            self.selectedMerchant = {'name': 'John'};
            self.show = function() {
                alert(JSON.stringify(self.selectedMerchant));
            }
            self.change = function() {
                self.selectedMerchant = {'name': 'David'};
            }
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new PartnersViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

'selectedMerchant' is declared without ko.observable(...), so it's supposed to be one-way binded. 
I expect that once I click the 'CHANGE' button, the text inside the input box will change to be 'David'. I also tried the different direction - I changed the text inside the input and clicked 'SHOW' button. The message box gave the initial value it had at the beginning.

Comment: You can do that by NOT declaring the property as observable. So it will only be bind 1 time and won't happen the other way around.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. It doesn't show the ONE-WAY from the model to the view.

Comment: I think M. Ihasn is correct, maybe update the question to show your JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a true one-way binding that will continue to update the UI you can use a computed observable. Unless you specify a "write" property for the computed it will only update in the model->UI direction. That being said you can achieve the same result by just replacing your input box with a span or label to prevent the user from updating the value, so I'm not sure I see the utility of a one-way binding.

```js
function PartnersViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedMerchant = ko.observable({'name': 'John'});
    self.show = function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify(self.selectedMerchant()));
    }
    self.change = function() {
        self.selectedMerchant({'name': 'David'});
    }
    self.selectedName = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.selectedMerchant().name;
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new PartnersViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
<div data-bind="with: selectedMerchant">
  <input data-bind="value: $parent.selectedName"></input>
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.change"> CHANGE </button>
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.show"> SHOW </button>
</div>
```

If you want something a bit more reusable you can make a custom binding that only implements a single direction:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.oneWayValue = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        element.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is one thing I don't understand. 'data-bind="with: selectedMerchant"' is supposed to make the binding context attached to 'selectedMerchant' object. So, when I see:
<input data-bind="value: change"> I understand that change is supposed to be a property of selectedMerchant. But, it's not, and still it works. If so, what is the benefit of using 'data-bind: with' ?

Comment: @CrazySynthax You are correct, the `with` binding is supposed to change the context, and so the bindings should be `value: $parent.selectedName` and `click: $parent.change`. The reason it still works in this case is actually because of a bug. Your view model is doing something quite strange; the properties are being attached to `self`, but `self` is undefined so the properties are global. You need to declare "self" at the top of your viewmodel like `var self = this;`

Comment: "The Window.self read-only property returns the window itself." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self

Answer (score 2):

To expand on M. Ihsan's correct answer, Knockout will bind one way when not using observables, and using normal JavaScript variables/objects. Here is an example.

```js
function ExampleObject(one, two) {
  var self = this;

  self.one = one;
  self.two = ko.observable(two);

  self.ChangeVariables = function() {
    self.one = "1";
    self.two("2");
    console.log(self.one, ko.toJS(self.two));
  }
}


function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.bindingExample = ko.observableArray();

  self.Load = function() {
    self.bindingExample.push(new ExampleObject("one way", "two ways"));
    self.bindingExample.push(new ExampleObject("one way", "two ways"));
    self.bindingExample.push(new ExampleObject("one way", "two ways"));
    self.bindingExample.push(new ExampleObject("one way", "two ways"));
  }

  self.Load();

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1 way</th>
      <th>2 way</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: bindingExample">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: one"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: two"></td>
      <td> <a data-bind="click: ChangeVariables"> Change Variables</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `with` binding is already a one-way binding, as are most bindings. They're one-way from the model to the view, but this requires the model value to be an observable.

`value` is normally a two-way binding. The one-way nature described in the documentation is from view to model, which isn't the direction you want anyway.

In other words, you need `selectedMerchant` to be observable.